# Are these statements equal ?(java.nio)

Tags: java

I am trying to understand java.nio.I am making simple echo server.
Suppose we got keyCycler - which is iterator and then:

```
SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)keyCycler.next();
//Retrieve set of ready ops for
//this key (as a bit pattern)...
int keyOps = key.readyOps();
if ((keyOps & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)== SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)
```

I want to know wheather this

```
if ((keyOps & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)== SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)
```

always equal to this

```
    if(key.isAcceptable())
```

if no, in which cases they are different. Probably I got the whole thing wrong..

Comment: They are very nearly identical: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.java#359 (and *are* identical if the bitmask of which OP_ACCEPT has mutually-exclusive bits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.java/#359):

```
return (readyOps() & OP_CONNECT) != 0;
```

Since the bitmask of which `OP_CONNECT` has mutually-exclusive bits, this is identical to your code.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.java#SelectionKey.0OP_CONNECT

Comment: why they do so?:         public static final int OP_CONNECT = 1 << 3;     Can't they    public static final int OP_CONNECT = 8

Comment: Thank you for the preveious answer

Comment: @ArturArsalanov because it's easier to see by eye that `1 << 3` is a power of 2, and thus has exactly 1 bit set. I mean, for small powers, it's pretty easy, but I think that `1 << 20` is a lot easier to grok than 1045876. (Do you see the intentional typo?).